# How to display a property instead of the value in a databound DataGridViewComboBox?

Tags: c#, data-binding

I'm new to C# and .NET

I need to display the matching name of a value in a databound DatagridViewComboBox, but I can't figure out how to do that.

I have the following code:

```
bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = typeof(CR);

dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
Column1.Width = 400;
Column1.DataPropertyName = "CR_NAME";
Column2.DataPropertyName = "CR_STATE_S";
Column2.ValueMember = "CR_STATE_S";
Column2.DisplayMember = "GetStateName";

Column2.Items.Add("0"); // how to set the matching value here?
Column2.Items.Add("1");
Column2.Items.Add("2");

dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

GetStateName is a property of the CR Class that returns the matching name of the CR state. I need to display the state name in the combo box. How to do that? Thanks.

Comment: Your question is rather incomplete. I have to guess: If the column's value is set, then the matching item from the DropDown is displayed automatically. If it isn't, there is no match. Are 0,1,2 really your CR_STATE_S values?

Comment: Yes, the CR state can be 0, 1 or 2 and when the column's value is set, the matching value returned by GetStateName is displayed

Comment: OK. Now what is your question? Note that the combobox is only visible when it is dropped down; when it is closed what you see is the column. (This is different from a ComboBox, which always has a visible Text portion also.)

Comment: I need to use a lookup combo box, where only matching values are displayed (ex: zero, one, two), not the key (i.e. 0, 1 or 2). When a value is selected in the combobox, the underlying CR_STATE_S of the object is updated with the matching key (0, 1 or 2). I know that it is possible to setup a lookup table for the combobox through the DataSource, DisplayMember and ValueMember, but I dont know how to do that with databinding, where the DataPropertyName is used instead of the DataSource.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand all you wrote. Where will the lookup values come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display something different from the values the cells shall contain, then you can't simply load one thing into the Items of the ComboBoxCells.

Instead you need a DataSource that has at least different fields for the two things you want to use:

- A field for the visible representation of the data, called `DisplayMember`
- And a field for the actual data values, called `ValueMember`

These fields can sit in a `DataTable` but you can also use any other collection with suitable properties.

Lets create a very simple class and have a List of that class:

```
class itemClass
{
    public string display { get; set;}
    public string value { get; set; }
    public itemClass(string d, string v) 
    { display = d; value = v;}
}

List<itemClass> myItems = new List<itemClass>();

private void loadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // load the list with all values:
    myItems.Add(new itemClass("zero", "0"));
    myItems.Add(new itemClass("one", "1"));
    myItems.Add(new itemClass("two", "2"));
    myItems.Add(new itemClass("three", "3"));
    myItems.Add(new itemClass("four", "4"));
    myItems.Add(new itemClass("five", "5"));
    myItems.Add(new itemClass("six", "6"));

    // prepare the DataGridView 'DGV':
    DGV.Columns.Clear();
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell cCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    DGV.Columns.Add(cCol);
    cCol.DisplayMember = "display";
    cCol.ValueMember = "value";
    cCol.DataSource = myItems;
    cCol.ValueType = typeof(string);

    // add a few rows, for testing:
    DGV.Rows.Add(7);
    for (int i = 0; i < DGV.Rows.Count; 
        i++) DGV.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = i + "";
}
```

In the example I load the `Items` manually. Usually you will want to pull the values from the database or some other source. You can do that either by loading the datasource list as above or you can have a lookup table either independently or in in a `DataSet`.

If all cells need to have individual lookup values you need to load them separately and not use the column but each of the cells cast to `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`.